# AzureDevops how to add bug into backlog navigation list

Tags: azure-devops

I have got a simple backlog hierarchy, feature and a list of bugs.

We want to see bugs in the Kanban board and move its status from one to another. What I have done is

- enabled "bugs are managed with requirment" in Settings->Working with bugs
- enabled "Bug" in Settings->Annotations

On the board, I can filter to see "Features" but can't see "Bug" in the backlog list. Thus I wouldn't able to use Kanban to show bug status.

Any suggestions here?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I'm not quite sure if this question is suited for this site, as It doesn't directly involve programming. However I won't flag this yet, as you've wrote a good question so far.

Comment: I've just tried this and was seeing the same issue to start with - I'd only enabled the first setting you mentioned "Bugs are managed with requirements". After checking permissions / project settings etc and returning to the Kanban board, the bug was suddenly showing up in the "New" column. Maybe try a hard refresh? New private tab?

Comment: Also make sure you select Stories (and not Features) on the top right - that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have Stories selected (top right), not Features.

[image: Azure DevOps Kanban board filtered to Stories]

[image: Azure DevOps Kanban board filtered to Features]

Comment: nice! It helped me so much! Is there a way to "merge" all visualizations for some reason?